# Does slice or index of chainer.Variable to get item in chainer has backward ability?

Tags: chainer

Does the following code **chainer.Variable still have ability** to hold graph and can backward (gradient flow) after slice(a[0,1] or index(a[0]):

```
>>> a = chainer.Variable(np.array([[1,2,3],[10,11,12]]))
>>> a
variable([[ 1,  2,  3],
          [10, 11, 12]])
>>> a[0]
variable([1, 2, 3])
>>> a[0, 1]
variable([1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Indexing of `chainer.Variable` supports backprop.

Comment: chainer is the most easy to use NN network I have ever found(but till now it is not well known enough compared to other framework, by the way, I think pytorch copy your idea). I and my Berkeley friend use it to research reinforcement learning. Fighting!

Comment: Concretely, `get_item` function is used when `Variable` is accessed by index.
https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/master/chainer/functions/array/get_item.py#L93

Comment: I saw the code, Suppose still don't get the point how does slice or get_item back prop